# Can I use CURL to call same file?

Tags: php, curl

My file displays different content based on different Query Strings.
So for eg, it displays different data for  example.com/test.php?a=1 and example.com/test.php?b=1.
Now I want to read contents of same page when using other parameter.
So for eg read contents of test.php?a=1 from code of test.php?b=1
Is that possible?

file_get_contents is not working either.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. Show me the parameter you are passing to the `file_get_contents`.

Comment: use $_GET['a'],$_GET['b'] and have this in 'if else'  block and do your function accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If your script process `a` and `b` differently. It will send different data to you.